# From DateTime.TryParse, determine how each character in the input string was mapped to the parsed DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

When DateTime.TryParse succeeds, is there any way to determine what information was provided and what remained at default values? I see that the System.Globalization.DateTimeResult struct has this information, but it's internal and is not returned to me, so I can't access it.

My goal is to determine the precision (e.g. whether time of day or time zone were specified) for when I convert it to a standard format (I would like to specify only as much information as I have).

Comment: The answer to your first paragraph is no.  For the second, you haven't given us enough information to answer.  Please edit your question to expand on what possible kinds of input values you might receive, and what exactly you're wanting to know.  Also, you might want to demonstrate research effort and/or show what you've tried already.  If you were just wanting to take any random string and intelligently determine what it contains, sorry - that has LOTS of problems.  Consider the string `"012345"`, for example.

Comment: @MattJohnson Well ideally I would like it to work the same way that DateTime.TryParse does. I'm sure if I passed "012345" into that method without an explicit format string, it would fail. I know there are lots of problems, but DateTime has solved most of them using cultures, so it would be great to be able to re-use that work. There are currently only about 10 formats that I need to support, so I could just hard-code it. That would just mean adding a new line a few times a year when we add support for new inputs (we parse reports from PLC compilers, which are updated every now and then).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good solution for you.  If it were me, I would want to be explicit about which format I was expecting from each input.  I wouldn't want to leave anything to chance.  In other words, rather than having 10 different formats that are supported now and 11 when another kind of input is added to the system, I'd explicitly have: input A expects date format 1, input B expects date format 2, etc.